# How do I implement neo4j in scala?

Tags: scala, neo4j

I planning to implement neo4j in my project and wanted to use scala.
Could anyone suggest whether to use neo4j-scala wrapper(https://github.com/FaKod/neo4j-scala/)
or should I implement from the scratch?

Also is there any documentation for neo4j-scala wrapper (and also looking for some examples)?

Comment: I can testify that it's pretty easy to use Neo4j from Scala directly. It's probably even easier to use the Scala wrapper (I've never tried), but that will depend on your relative levels of comfort with Java and Scala. `neo4j-scala` does seem reasonably well-documented, though, and does include an `examples` directory and tests. If you want API docs you can always grab the repo and run `mvn scala:doc` locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use https://github.com/wfreeman/AnormCypher which is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515865/using-neo4j-with-scala). I'd suggest to look at [gremlin-scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer ;)