# Cypher query in Scala

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Am new to both Scala and Neo4j. Am developing a project in Scala with Neo4j as database using Scala-Neo4j wrapper. Is there any support for Cypher in this wrapper? If so, how do I write a cypher query in Scala?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using neo4j with scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515865/using-neo4j-with-scala)

Answer (score 0):

Have raised https://github.com/FaKod/neo4j-scala/issues/17, feel free to work on it and contribute!

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather simple "typed" Cypher call support:

The following example shows how to use Cypher together with typed results. In this case "execute" returns the case class Test_Matrix.

```
class MyClass extends Neo4jWrapper with SingletonEmbeddedGraphDatabaseServiceProvider with Cypher {
    . . .
    val query = "start n=node(" + nodeId + ") return n, n.name"

    val typedResult = query.execute.asCC[Test_Matrix]("n")

    typedResult.next.name must be_==("Neo")
    . . .
}
```

Test case is here: https://github.com/FaKod/neo4j-scala/blob/0.2.0-M/src/test/scala/org/neo4j/scala/unittest/CypherTest.scala